# Debug PHP in CLI mode using Xdebug and PHP Debug extension

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, xdebug

I am unable to set debugging from CLI on localhost (Launch currently open script configuration in PHP Debug)
The script runs, but ignores any breakpoints.
Otherwise, debugging PHP in browser works fine.

My setup, launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "port": 9000,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.1\\php.exe",
            "env": {"XDEBUG_CONFIG" : "remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1 remote_connect_back=0"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": ["-dxdebug.remote_enable=1", "-dxdebug.remote_mode=req",  "-dxdebug.remote_port=9000", "-dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1", "-dxdebug.remote_connect_back=0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Xdebug section in php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.1/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.9.0-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/wamp64/tmp"
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

I tried experimenting with different setups, as you see from settings, but to no avail.

EDIT:this is log file from debugging:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true
}

<- outputEvent
OutputEvent {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'event',
  event: 'output',
  body: { category: 'stdout', output: 'gotovo!' }
}

gotovo!
<- terminatedEvent
TerminatedEvent { seq: 0, type: 'event', event: 'terminated' }

-> disconnectRequest
{
  command: 'disconnect',
  arguments: { restart: false },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have same possibility on terminal cli,
because you don 't use php module.
here is only inside the sever apache or nginx.